# Gmail API Java Implementation Error (Credentials not found)

Tags: java, gmail-api

I try to implement the code of GmailAPI, but the code doesn't find the credentials.jar. I put a file.exists() verification inside of the google default code, and I find them on that location. So why I see the File Not Found error in the executation ?

Here is the google default code with my file verification:

```
private static Credential getCredentials(final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT) throws IOException {
        //Verify if the directory of credentials exists:
        File credentials = new File(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
        if(credentials.exists()){
            System.out.print("The credentials directory exists! --> "+credentials.getAbsolutePath());
        }
        // Load client secrets.
        InputStream in = GmailAPI.class.getResourceAsStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
        if (in == null) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Resource not found: " + CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
        }
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

        // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                .setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(new java.io.File(TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH)))
                .setAccessType("offline")
                .build();
        LocalServerReceiver receiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8888).build();
        return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, receiver).authorize("user");
    }
```

And here is the output of execution:

```
The credentials directory exists! --> C:\rfp\GymSoft\Google\credentials.json
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: Resource not found: Google/credentials.json
    at apoio.GmailAPI.getCredentials(GmailAPI.java:43)
    at apoio.GmailAPI.main(GmailAPI.java:61)
C:\rfp\GymSoft\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1340: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\rfp\GymSoft\nbproject\build-impl.xml:981: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)
```

Comment: Google/credentials.json is not the same as C:\rfp\GymSoft\Google\credentials.json. print the entire path in your errorµ

Comment: It seems simply file handling issue, nothing specific to GmailAPI. You already create a `File` object to check whether the file exists. Use his object to open the stream as well. eg: `GmailAPI.class.getResourceAsStream(credentials.getAbsolutePath)`

Answer (score 1):

You must put your `credentials.json` file in your ***project's resources folder***, then just declare a constant and implement it in your code:

```
private static final String CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH = "/credentials.json";
InputStream in = GmailAPI.class.getResourceAsStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
```

By default, That is the place where GmailAPI searches the `credentials.json` file unless you set an absolute path, but to avoid troubles it's better to simply put it there in the ***resources folder***.

You can check a quickstart Gmail API example using Java [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/java).